# Is there a built in function to compute the difference of two sets?

Tags: rust, set

New to Rust. Pretty simple question, I searched for a while and couldn't find an answer

Basically I want something like this

```
let mut v1 = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut v2 = vec![3, 4];
assert_eq!(v1 - v2, &[0, 1, 2]);

let mut v1 = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let mut v2 = vec![3, 4];
assert_eq!(v1 - v2, &[0, 1, 2, 5, 6]);

let mut v1 = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let mut v2 = vec![7];
assert_eq!(v1 - v2, &[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear how that is supposed to work. What if `v2` isn't a suffix of `v1`?

Comment: Im adding more examples

Comment: Vectors are not sets, so such an operation wouldn't be efficient and is not defined. See [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) instead.

Comment: From the examples it looks like you want to remove elements in both vectors from the first vector. Sets would be a good way to go about doing that for a large number of elements. For a smaller number vectors would be acceptable and could even be faster.

Comment: What's the expected result for `[1, 1, 2, 2] - [1, 2]`? Does order matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your examples, it seems that you're looking for vectors where the elements are unique.

Vectors don't actually guarantee this property (items don't have to be unique or ordered, indeed, they don't even have to support comparison), but Sets do ([HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) or [BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html)). And HashSet indeed supports the `-` operator:

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ab40ef61fe45e21795f1cfad0915ad7))

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let s1: HashSet<i32> = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].iter().cloned().collect();
    let s2: HashSet<i32> = [3, 4].iter().cloned().collect();
    let expected: HashSet<i32> = [0, 1, 2].iter().cloned().collect();
    assert_eq!(&s1 - &s2, expected);
}
```

If you want to perform this operation on vectors, you could convert to HashSet or BTreeSet and then create a vector from this:

```rust
fn vect_difference(v1: &Vec<i32>, v2: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let s1: HashSet<i32> = v1.iter().cloned().collect();
    let s2: HashSet<i32> = v2.iter().cloned().collect();
    (&s1 - &s2).iter().cloned().collect()
}
```

Or you could perform the difference directly on the vectors (keeping in mind that this is an O(N*M) algorithm and would perform poorly if both vectors are long):

```rust
fn vect_difference(v1: &Vec<i32>, v2: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v1.iter().filter(|&x| !v2.contains(x)).cloned().collect()
}
```

Comment: For function arguments, it's a good idea to use a slice `&[T]` instead of a vector `&Vec<T>`. Shared reference to vec adds an unnecessary indirection when accessing data and doesn't provide any benefit over `&[T]`. A slice, on the other hand, can be obtained from any contiguously stored data, not just that in a vector.

Comment: Fully agree re slices vs Vec. I wanted to keep the example Vec focused since that is what the OP is working with. I think it is always a question of how much best practices to drag into a post - maybe going with `&[T]` would have been better here, but sometimes you end up explaining too many tagential points this way...

Comment: @Paul depending how long v2 is, it might be worth converting *just* that to a Set upfront, to avoid paying the O(n) membership lookup on every element of v1.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I'd just make the post accept `&[i32]` without a dedicated explanation, as slices are basic enough that any Rust tutorial will cover them. But, as you are aware of the best practice, it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

To remove elements from one vector that are in another:

```rust
fn subtract(a: &Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut c = a.clone();
    c.retain(|x| !b.contains(x));
    c
}
```

or if you're okay with mutating the first vector:

```rust
fn subtract(a: &mut Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>) {
    a.retain(|x| !b.contains(x));
}
```

Note this is an O(N*M) algorithm where N,M are the lengths of the vectors.

This is fast for a small number of elements. For larger number you might use a `HashSet`. The [`difference`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.difference) method provides an applicable example, building the sets from vectors initially.

Here's my version, which only makes one `HashSet` and is therefore faster if you start with two vectors and want to end with a vector. This is similar to what `difference()` does under the hood.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
let b: HashSet<_> = v2.into_iter().collect();
v1.retain(|x| !b.contains(x));
```

This will be O(M+N): M to build the hash set from the second vector, and N to check each element in the first vector.